# CodeIgniter Upload path is not valid

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-3

CodeIgniter upload class does is not returning the right `full_path`. I am trying to upload an image. I write up this code

```
$config['encrypt_name']     = TRUE; 
echo $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH .'contest/videos/';
$config['max_size']         = '1000000000000000';
$config['allowed_types']    = '*';
$config['file_name']        = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

But it keeps asking that the permission denied. When I check the `$this->upload->data()` I see the `full_path` does not have last trailing slash after the last folder. See the `print_r` result

```
Array
(
    [file_name] => testvdo.mp4
    [file_type] => 
    [file_path] => /var/www/html/zebra_1975/contest/videos
    [full_path] => /var/www/html/zebra_1975/contest/videostestvdo.mp4
    [raw_name] => testvdo.mp4
    [orig_name] => 
    [client_name] => 
    [file_ext] => 
    [file_size] => 
    [is_image] => 
    [image_width] => 
    [image_height] => 
    [image_type] => 
    [image_size_str] => 
)
```

There should be a slash after `video` in `full_path`. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: echo $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH .'contest/videos/'; what is Output of this ??

Comment: If the error message is talking about permission denied then you need to set the correct permissions on that folder. So what have you set the permissions to for that folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope it will help you to set yours properly.

```php
if (isset($_FILES['profile_img']) && !empty($_FILES['profile_img']['name']))
{
    $user_img_path = './public/uploads/images/users/';

    $config['upload_path'] = $user_img_path;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
    $config['file_name'] = $img_name;
    $config['max_size']  = '9999';
    $config['max_width']  = '1524';
    $config['max_height']  = '868';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('profile_img')){

        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        print_r($error);
    }
    else{
        $image = $this->upload->data();
        print_r($image);
    }

}
```

I am using this in my project

So for me I used this and is working for me

```php
$user_img_path = './public/uploads/images/users/';
```

OR

```php
$user_img_path = FCPATH'./public/uploads/images/users/';
```

OR
Editing Yours

```php
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH .'/contest/videos/';
```

Instead of

```php
$user_img_path = FCPATH .'contest/videos/';
```

So try it. If it work for you let me know I am here to help